# nginx access log as json with query string key value pairs

Tags: nginx, http

I want to make a custom nginx access log that is not only JSON but also has JSON key:value pairs for every key=value in the query.

Making a JSON log for nginx is easy:

```
log_format main '{'
                 '"remote_addr": "$remote_addr",'
                 '"remote_user": "$remote_user",'
                 '"time_local":  "$time_local",'
                 '"request":     "$request",'
                 '"status":      "$status",'
                 '"body_bytes_sent": "$body_bytes_sent",'
                 '"http_referer": "$http_referer",' 
                 '"http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent"'
                 '}';
```

However lets say the request was `GET /blah?foo=bar&hi=there%20mom`

I'm looking for 2 additional things in the json

`...
'http_user_agent':'chrome',
'foo':'bar',
'hi':'there mom'
}`

Can this be done? If so how can I make sure the resulting JSON is valid? (decodes URL escapes etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the [HttpSetMiscModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSetMiscModule) ([GitHub Repo](https://github.com/agentzh/set-misc-nginx-module)). You'll have to compile nginx yourself to include this module.

Afterwards you can do things like:

```
GET /blah?foo=bar&hi=there%20mom

set $foo $arg_foo;
set $hi $arg_hi;
set_quote_json_str $foo;
set_quote_json_str $hi;
log_format main '{'
    '"remote_addr": "$remote_addr",'
    '"remote_user": "$remote_user",'
    '"time_local":  "$time_local",'
    '"request":     "$request",'
    '"status":      "$status",'
    '"body_bytes_sent": "$body_bytes_sent",'
    '"http_referer": "$http_referer",' 
    '"http_user_agent": "$http_user_agent"'
    '"arg_foo": "$foo"'
    '"arg_hi": "$hi"'
'}';
```

**Please note that I haven't tested this!**

Comment: Interesting. However that requires you to know all the params ahead of time and/or have different configs for each web service (that has diff params) that you wish to log. I'm looking for a generic way to take every key/value and log it (access log)

Comment: I understood that, but that's not possible as far as I'm aware. You could of course ask Igor itself but I doubt that there is a solution.

You know what I'd do. Simply log `$args` and process it with the script that retrieves the JSON answer. It's very easy with JavaScript, jQuery, PHP, etc. to work with JSON.

Comment: Understand, thx. Gonna mark this as the answer as I think this is close as you can get with just nginx